# e is primitive iff e$\mathbb{F}G$e is a skew field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules

This question comes from the decomposition of group algebra.

For field $\mathbb{F}$ and finite group G, ch($\mathbb{F})\nmid|G|$, I have known that for idempotent e $\in \mathbb{F}(G)$, $\mathbb{F}(G)\cdot e$ is a minimal left ideal if and only if $e$ is a primitive idempotent.

In the notes, there is a proposition that e is primitive if and only if $e\cdot \mathbb{F}(G)\cdot e$ is a skew field, but I don't know how to prove it.

Could you give me any hints? Any comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with and allowed to assume the Wedderburn-Artin Theorem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will go to learn about such theorem first.

Comment: @Rookie He might be talking about Maschke's theorem (which says under your hypotheses any $F(G)$ module is semisimple.) This would indeed be useful to help show that $F(G)e$ is a minimal left ideal, but you already know that, and I'm not sure it carries you across the line proving $eF(G)e$ is a division ring. No need to spend too much time with the W-A theorem: there's an elementary proof.

Answer (score 1):

The main bit you're missing is this lemma:

> For any ring $R$ with idempotent $e$
> $$(eRe)^{op}\cong \mathrm{End}(_RRe)$$ as rings

You wrote that under your hypotheses, you had proven that $e$ is primitive implied $Re$ is a minimal left ideal (i.e. a simple left $R$ module. Then its endomorphism ring is of course a division ring (that's just Schur's lemma.)  And of course a ring is a division ring iff its opposite ring is a division ring.

The lemma is not too hard to prove. The map is what you'd expect: an element of $eRe$ induces an $R$ homomorphism of $Re$ by right multiplication.  You should have no problems showing it's an injective ring homomorphism that reverses multiplication in $eRe$.

Surjectivity is also not hard. Suppose that $f:Re\to Re$ is left $R$ linear. Then $f(e)=re$ for some $r$.  By left linearity you also have $f(e)=ef(e)=ere$. Finally for any $x\in R$ at all, $f(xe)=xf(e)=xere$. So for our original choice $f$, we have found $ere$ that maps to $f$.

Comment: Are there any typos in your answer? I think you mean $End_R (Re)$? And I still do not know how to prove they are isomorphic... I know that $End_R (R)$ is isomorphic to $R^{op}$. Could you please inform me how to prove what you claim?

Comment: @Rookie No, I do not mean $End(_RR)$ is isomorphic to $R^{op}$, but that is a special case with $e=1$.  Just check it out: every $R$ endomorphism of $Re$ turns out to be right multiplication by an element of $eRe$.

Comment: I have a question about the claim: if e is primitive then $End_R(Re)$ is a skew field. Could you please offer any more details?

Comment: @Rookie You wrote that you had already proven that $Re$ is a minimal ideal if $e$ is primitive, under your hypotheses.  The endomorphism ring of a simple $R$ module (such as a minimal left ideal) is a division ring: this is just Schur's lemma.

Comment: @Rookie I appreciate your offer to expand my answer, but in this case I guess it's incumbent upon me to do so. I've expanded it a bit and I hope it's what you were looking for.